# HTA/VbScript - If statement from Dropdown list choice

Tags: vbscript, hta

In my HTA using `vbscript` I am trying to read a choice from a DropDown list that will run specific code for each choice.

I've been poking around looking for some method to use the value of a DropDown list to run a specific `VBSCRIPT subroutine` but have not found anything helpful in my search.  The code below does work however it only displays a message box with the choice listed.  Any pointers would be extremely appreciated!!

```
<select name="BuildStepChoice" size="1">
 <option selected="selected" value=" "></option>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
</select> &nbsp;
```

And the `VBSCRIPT`

```
Sub Copychecklist()
Dim VMBuildStep
VMBuildStep = document.getElementById("BuildStepChoice").Value
 If VMBuildStep = 1 Then MsgBox "Picked #1" Else
 If VMBuildStep = 2 Then MsgBox "Picked #2" End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It cannot be as simple as `If VMBuildStep = 1 Then Call Step1 Else` but it seems that way.

Comment: <select name="BuildStepChoice" onChange="Copychecklist()"  size="1">

Comment: Thank you @JosefZ as it often happens to me, I hit upon my answer shortly after posting the question!

Comment: If you have a  solution, then answer yourself.  Read and follow [answer]  and [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) as well.

Comment: Somehow the Answer Your Question button when clicked does nothing.  The answer in my case was as simple as using `If VMBuildStep = 1 Then Call Step1 Else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where I picked this up, but this is what I ended up with.

```
Sub Copychecklist()
 Dim VMBuildStep
 VMBuildStep = document.getElementById("BuildStepChoice").Value
  If (IsNumeric(VMBuildStep)) Then
  VMBuildStep = Int(VMBuildStep)
  If (VMBuildStep >= 1 And VMBuildStep <= 17) Then CreateFile(VMBuildStep)
 End If            
End Sub
```